# Imagemagick linear invert as in Gimp?

Tags: imagemagick-convert, gimp

I'd like to LINEAR invert image in Imagemagick with the same output as in Gimp.

Original image:

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnHVi.jpg)

Gimp invert:

[Gimp invert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYJHo.jpg)

Gimp LINEAR invert:

[Gimp LINEAR invert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAYac.jpg)

Imagemagick "negate" function:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYSBl.jpg)

Which function should I use then? In Imagemagick documentation I didn't found "linear invert".

Comment: Your Imagemagick negate looks like GIMP linear invert?  What did you do in Imagemagick, since I get a result similar to GIMP invert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your Imagemagick version and platform?  When I do the following on IM 6.9.13.3 on Mac OSX Ventura, I get

```
convert map.jpg -negate x.jpg
```

[image]

That looks like a proper invert for the input and seems to match GIMP result.

```
compare -metric rmse x.jpg GIMP.jpg null:
135.592 (0.00206901)
```

The comparison shows only a 0.2% difference between the IM result and the GIMP result.

**ADDITION**

From the GIMP docs, the inversion is done in linear colorspace.  So in Imagemagick,

```
convert map.jpg -colorspace rgb -negate -colorspace sRGB map_linear_invert.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. I use ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The results of "negate" in Imagemagick and "invert" in Gimp are very similar but I want to get the effect like in Gimp's linear invert - not "ordinary" invent.

Comment: What is GIMP linear invert supposed to do different from a normal invert?  Do you have an algorithm? Or description of the function?

Comment: OK. See my ADDITION in my answer above.

Comment: GREAT! This is exactly the same output image :) Compare shows 0.0% of difference! Big thanks for investigating this.